# Migrar base de datos SQL Server a Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy tratando de migrar una base de datos de `SQL Server` a `Oracle`, para esto estoy utilizando `Oracle SQL Developer` como lo sugiere el siguiente 
[Tutorial de Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-sqlserver-1945229.html), el cual tiene las siguientes secciones:

- Conexión:


    1. Instalar Oracle SQL Developer




    2. Crear y configurar repositorio de migración:

a) Asignara permisos: `Grant connect, resource, create session, create view to migration_repo identified by migration_repo;`

b) Conectar a repositorio creado:

```
Nombre de Conexión: migration_repo 
Usuario: migration_repo 
Contraseña: migration_repo 
SID: MYSID_ORACLE
```

C) Asociar Repositorio: Herramientas/Migración/Gestión de Repositorios/Crear Repositorio, elegir "`migration_repo`"
[image: Asociar Repositorio]

3. Conectar a base de datos de tercero

- Captura
- Convertir
- Transferir
- Generar
- Mover Data

Sigo los pasos anteriores, pero al finalizar la sección transferir me sale el siguiente error:

[image: PLS-00201: el identificador 'SS2K5ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE']

Error:

```
<message>Error:ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 14:
    PLS-00201: el identificador 'SS2K5ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' se debe declarar
    ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    : FAILED : Migración de Base de Datos : FAILED</message>
```

Información completa del Log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<log>
<record>
  <date>2016-06-01T16:48:18</date>
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.MigrationLogUtil</class>
  <message>Capture
Enterprise Capture
Capture failed.  Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details</message>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doOnlineEnterpriseCapture(FullMigrateTask.java:758)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doCapture(FullMigrateTask.java:601)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doMaskBasedActions(FullMigrateTask.java:400)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doWork(FullMigrateTask.java:314)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doWork(FullMigrateTask.java:147)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:621)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)</param>
  <param>java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.LogInfo@572aa33a</param>
  <exception>
    <message>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask$FullMigrateTaskException: Capture
Enterprise Capture
Capture failed.  Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details</message>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>758</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>601</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>400</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>314</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>147</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask</class>
      <line>193</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask</class>
      <line>266</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask</class>
      <line>621</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter</class>
      <line>511</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask</class>
      <line>266</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor</class>
      <line>1142</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker</class>
      <line>617</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.lang.Thread</class>
      <line>745</line>
    </frame>
  </exception>

</record>
<record>
  <date>2016-06-01T16:48:18</date>
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
  <message>Error:ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 14:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'SS2K5ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
: FAILED : Migración de Base de Datos : FAILED</message>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.LogInfo@7e8e4394</param>
```

**Herramientas:**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012
- Oracle 11g V2
- Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3.20.78
- Java (TM) 1.80_60
- jtds-1.2-dist

Comment: Estas seguro que es SQL Server 2011 ?

Comment: Ups, no, es SQL Server 2012. corregido, gracias @fredyfx!

Comment: listo! de nada :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé, si es la mejor solución, pero resolví la situación con los siguientes pasos.

1. Modificar los privilegios del repositorio de migración `Grant ALL
   PRIVILEGES to migration_repo identified by migration_repo;`
2. Eliminar repositorio creado "migration_repo"
3. Eliminar conexión a migration_repo
4. Iniciar de nuevo con los pasos del tutorial

Comment: Me agrada cuando uno mismo logra hacer funcionar lo propuesto, en especial cuando comparten de buena fe :D

Answer (score 0):

Se que este tema está cerrado pero tengo un problema parecido. Estoy siguiendo estos mismos pasos y la migración finaliza correctamente, pero las tablas que me ha creado están vacías.

Creo que mi problema es que estoy mirando el esquema equivocado. Cuando finaliza la migración reviso lo que en tu caso se llama "migration_repo" y no tiene datos. Este esquema se crea como soporte para la migración y tiene sentido que no tenga datos. Pero entonces, ¿Que esquema es el que contendrá los datos? 
He probado a conectarme como SYS en la bd de Oracle y hago un select count(*) de las tablas tampoco tienen datos.

Gracias y un saludo